# compile php5 on MacOS ElCapitan error

Tags: osx-el-capitan, php5

I'm trying to compile php 5.6.25 on MacOS Server 5 (aka ElCapitan) with these options:

```
    sudo ./configure \
--prefix=/usr/local/php5 \
--mandir=/usr/share/man \
--infodir=/usr/share/info \
--sysconfdir=/etc \
--with-config-file-path=/etc \
--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/php5/php.d \
--with-config-file-scan-dir=/Library/Server/Web/Config/php \
--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs \
--with-bz2=/usr  \
--with-curl=/usr \
--with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/php5 \
--with-gd \
--with-gettext \
--with-iconv-dir=/usr \
--with-imap-ssl=/usr/local \
--with-imap=/usr/local \
--with-iodbc=/usr \
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/php5 \
--with-kerberos=/usr \
--with-ldap \
--with-libxml-dir=/usr \
--with-mcrypt \
--with-mhash \
--with-mysql-sock=/var/mysql \
--with-mysql=/usr/local/mysql \
--with-pdo-mysql=/usr/local/mysql \
--with-mysqli=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config \
--with-openssl=/usr/local/include/openssl \
--with-pcre-regex \
--with-png-dir=/usr/local/php5 \
--with-snmp=/usr \
--with-t1lib=/usr/local/php5 \
--with-tidy \
--with-xmlrpc \
--with-xsl=/usr \
--with-zlib-dir=/usr \
--with-zlib=/usr \
--without-pear \
--enable-bcmath \
--enable-calendar \
--enable-cgi \
--enable-exif \
--enable-ftp \
--enable-gd-native-ttf \
--enable-mbstring \
--enable-pcntl \
--enable-shmop  \
--enable-soap \
--enable-mbregex \
--enable-sockets \
--enable-cli \
--enable-sysvmsg \
--enable-sysvsem \
--enable-sysvshm \
--enable-wddx \
--enable-zip
```

the first error I run in was the missing openSSL header files, so I installed it via homebrew.
But now I get:

```
checking "whether flock struct is linux ordered"... "no"
checking "whether flock struct is BSD ordered"... "no"
configure: error: Don't know how to define struct flock on this system, set --enable-opcache=no
```

With that option set it compiles, but I wonder, if it wouldnt be better to have that issue solved before.

Thanks

Comment: configure runs, make ends with an error:
In file included from /SourceCache/php-5.6.25/ext/odbc/php_odbc.c:37:
ext/odbc/php_odbc_includes.h:98:10: fatal error: 'iodbcext.h' file not found
#include <iodbcext.h>

Comment: error: 'iodbcext.h' solved throug installing libiobbc, but now I get unsupported size of off_t